# Can abstract object representations be associated with a wider range of sounds in comparison to everyday object representations?

Tags: reference-request, cross-modal

I'm looking for some peer reviewed evidence that abstract visuals can be associated with a wide range of sounds when compared to more recognisable visual representations pertaining to everyday objects.

For an abstract object we are unlikely to have formed any strong correlating bonds between the two modalities and therefore can't relate the sound it makes to our everyday experience.

In comparison, an object that we are very familiar with is not ideally suited to more abstract sounds as it doesn't match our expectations and therefore seems out of place.